# Is it inappropriate to turn a proof verification question into a self-answered question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, solution-verification

Over a week ago I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/861351/39599). In it, I proposed a solution and asked for it to be verified, or for an alternative solution to be suggested. Currently, there are no answers but there is one comment stating that my proof is correct (as well as indicating the need for more explanation of a certain claim which I have since addressed in an edit).

As I don't expect the question to get any more attention, I am considering removing the proof from the question and adding it as an answer. This would allow me to accept the answer which would remove the question from the unanswered queue. I wouldn't accept straight away, just in case bumping the question to the front page draws the attention of a user who may wish to answer. As for the comment, I was thinking of asking a moderator to move it to the answer (if that's even possible).

> Would this be considered inappropriate behaviour? If so, are there any suggestions for actions I should take instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that moving an answer to the answer is the best move. This improves the readability of the question for those who come across it later: users expect to find an answer is the answer box, not in the question.

You don't have to mark the answer CW; after all, you wrote it.

Moderators cannot move comments from one post to another. You can leave your own comment saying: "the answer to which user's comment referred is now posted below".

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese. Moderators cannot transfer comments from post to post. When an answer is converted to a comment, there is an option to also transfer the commentary beneath that answer, and when merging questions the comments on the questions are also merged. But there is no "move this specific comment to this specific post" functionality. (At least the mods don't have access to this functionality.  Presumably the comm team would be able to do this, but due to the intended ephemeral nature of comments, I am sure this is something they would be extremely reluctant to do.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Thanks for the clarification. I didn't want to make the proposed changes and leave the only feedback I received out of place, hence my concern over the comment. I will probably take the advice offered above.