# When someone confirms your answer is correct in an answer in the comments and another in the answer

Tags: discussion

I'm just wondering what the etiquette is in terms of getting a response to your question when it turns out to be the right answer. Sometimes, when you're doing the question from a book, the answers at the back of the book will only have the answers to the odd-numbered questions, so I, and I imagine a lot of others, use this site for verification for the questions where there are no answers at the back of the book.
Now I post a question, like I have done today, and it turns out to be correct, someone will say it is correct. However, one might say it in the comments and another will say that I'm correct as the answer.

It seems unfair that I accept the answer when others have simply answered in the comments too. As an answere, isn't there more advantage to confirm a correct an answer as an answer than a comment because then your answer can be accepted and get more points?

Comment: This is possibly related [How to answer proof-verification questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20097/how-to-answer-proof-verification-questions)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @kingW3